# Getting a random transversal for finite family of finite sets

Tags: algorithm, probability, combinatorics

I'm looking for an algorithm that takes a finite number of sets S_1, ..., S_n as an input and outputs a list x_1, ..., x_n where x_i belongs to S_i for i=1,..,n and all x_i are pairwise distinct. Note, that sets S_i will not be pairwise disjoint in general. We can call such list a transversal of family {S_1, ..., S_n}, as it is usually done.

The list should be randomly chosen in such way that each possible list is equally probable as an output. I don't care what happens, where no such list exists. I want the algorithm to be reasonably fast, in particular enumerating all lists before making the choice is considered too slow.

Comment: How big is n? How many different elements? Is approximately equiprobable OK?

Comment: In my opinion, this question is too broad. Also, it might be off-topic and instead belong to [Computer Science](https://cs.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: In the practical application I have in mind: n<10 and each S_n can have up to a couple of hundreds of elements.

Comment: And approximately equiprobable is OK

Answer (score 2):

As Ante observes, we're looking for a bipartite matching, but the hard part here is finding a random one. If your graph is large enough, then you probably have to settle for the rapidly mixing Markov chain of Jerrum and Sinclair. Otherwise, there's an O(2^n poly(n))-time dynamic program for counting maximum matchings (as opposed to the O(n!)-time algorithm for enumerating them), which you can use to sample by repeatedly counting the number of matchings after either using an edge or not to match.

Comment: This looks interesting. So I need to construct some Markov chain for my family of sets (or bipartite graph). Then each (long enough) random walk will point me to some solution and the probabilities will behave. But how to construct the chain? Also can you give me some useful links concerning the theory you refer to?

Comment: The dynamic programming approach looks promising as well, since n is small in my specific application.

Comment: @witzar Actually, it might suffice just to choose representatives independently and uniformly at random, retrying from scratch if there is a collision.

Comment: I'm afraid of this approach, since I fear it might lead to too many collisions on some evil cases, like S_n = {1, ... , n}.

Comment: @witzar Even if all n = 10 sets were {1, ..., 10}, you'd only have to retry a couple thousand times in expectation.

Comment: In the evil case from my previous comment probability of non-collision is 1/n!. For n=10 it means that I have to make about 3*10^7 tries before getting first non-collision. To clarify, the evil case is S_1={1}, S_2={1,2}, ..., S_10={1, 2, ..., 10}.

Answer (score 1):

Represent incidence of set and elements as bipartite graph and find [maximum cardinality bipartite matching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_(graph_theory)#Algorithms_and_computational_complexity).

Comment: Yes, searching for transversal of a family of sets is equivalent to searching for maximum matching of bipartite graph. And the problem of finding some maximum cardinality matching is well known. But I don't want just some.

Comment: It is possible to permute input (elements and/or sets) or even to put shuffling in step where algorithm choose next vertex in DFS.